# How can I partially serialize with GNU make

Tags: make, gnu, gnu-make, sunpro

When I have a make task where a specific target needs to be made before another, while in parallel mode, this is simple when using SunPro Make (dmake). The following makefile:

```
install:  dir dir/file

dir:
    mkdir dir

dir/file:
    cp source dir/file
```

could be made parallel make safe by changing the first line to:

```
install: dir .WAIT dir/file
```

or by using:

```
.NO_PARALLEL: install
```

The rest of the makefile will still be handled in parallel mode and even a list if targets to the left or to the right of `.WAIT` will be handled in parallel mode.

See: http://schilytools.sourceforge.net/man/man1/make.1s.html and http://schilytools.sourceforge.net/man/man1/dmake.1.html

but GNU make does not seem to have a similar option. Is there really no way to do this with GNU make?

To be more specific, the solution needs to be written in a way that allows the makefile to be processed with other make implementations.

The special target .WAIT could e.g. be in a make program dependent macro that is called e.g. $(WAIT)

Note that there is an apparent solution that does not help:

In theory one could make `dir` a dependency of `dir/file` in order to enforce to create `dir` before trying to copy to `dir/file,` but if you later copy another file into `dir,` this makes `dir` newer than `dir/file`. As a result, calling `make` more than once would copy to `dir/file`again and again, without the expected result from `make` to do the copy only in case that the source has become newer that `dir/file.`

This raises the alternate question whether there may be a topology of dependencies that enforces `make` to create `dir` before copying to `dir/file` without making `dir`a dependency of `dir/file.`

Comment: Maybe I'm low on coffee, but wouldn't it be enough to make `dir/file` depend on `dir`? (that is, `dir/file: dir`)

Comment: If you do this and later copy more files into dir, then dir/file would become outdated from the view of make while it is really up to date.

Comment: @schily: Oh, of course.

Comment: @stephen-penny: could you be more specific please? I cannot find .SECONDARY in the GNU make documentation.

Comment: http://gnu.org/software/make/manual/html_node/Chained-Rules

Comment: OK, this is for implicit rules while I need a partial order for explicit rules.

Comment: @schily it’s usable for explicit rules too (`dir/file: source dir` and `.SECONDARY: dir`), but it doesn’t deal with the directory update issue, so it doesn’t help here AFAICT.

Comment: perhaps .ONESHELL: can help you?

Comment: @kimstik `.ONESHELL` is nonstandard and completely unrelated to the problem.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here is the my own answer that has been derived from the idea presented by Filipe Brandenburger and from generic methods used in the Schily Makefile system:

The makefile system makes sure that the following `make macros` are set up this way:

```
WAIT=       # empty with GNU make
WAIT= .WAIT # .WAIT special target with SunPro Make

MAKEPROG= <name of the make program> # This is from: smake, gmake, sunpro

_UNIQ= .XxZzy-
```

Now the makefile that makes use from the macro definitions above:

```
_NORULE=    $(_UNIQ)$(MAKEPROG)
__NORULE=   $(_NORULE:$(_UNIQ)gmake=)
NORULE=     $(__NORULE:$(_UNIQ)%=%)

install: dir $(WAIT) dir/file

dir/file: source
        cp source dir/file

dir:
        mkdir -p dir

$(NORULE)dir/file: | dir
```

`$(NORULE)` expands to nothing with gmake and to `sunpro`with SunPro Make.

In case of gmake, the whole makefile expands to:

```
install: dir dir/file

dir/file: source
        cp source dir/file

dir:
        mkdir -p dir

dir/file: | dir
```

In case of SunPro Make, the whole makefile expands to:

```
install: dir .WAIT dir/file

dir/file: source
        cp source dir/file

dir:
        mkdir -p dir

sunprodir/file: | dir
```

The last line is seen as a junk rule with no relevance.

Comment: Glad you figured it out and happy I could help!

Comment: @schily The problem with the GNU one is: it has 2 single-colon rules for "dir/file". Only the last one encountered will be effective, previous ones will be ignored. The problem with both is that the order of processing prerequisites is undefined. It is possible that "dir/file" is built before "dir" when "dir" does not exist yet. Also, there is no target for "source". This should lead to a "don't know how to make 'source'" -type error, unless "source" exists. But in that case, why have it as a prerequisite in the first place? It never needs to be built.

Comment: @Larry 1) There of course is a make target for source, just not in that shown sniplet. 2)   The general rule for makefiles is that you definitely may have more than a single explicit rule for a target as long as there is only only one rule with actions. In such a case, all rules are added.

Comment: @schily You are right, it is possible to add dependencies or - in the case of GNU make -, target-specific variables using duplicate single-colon rules. What about prerequisite build order though?

Answer (score 9):

In GNU make, you can use *order-only-prerequisites* to make sure `dir` is created before the rule to create `dir/file` is run.

See [this page](https://www.gnu.org/software/make/manual/html_node/Prerequisite-Types.html) for more details.

You can see from the example in GNU make's manual that it's really tailored for adding dependency on a directory being created before creating files under it.

In the case of your specific example, something like this should do it:

```
dir/file: | dir
        cp source dir/file
```

Though you don't need to modify the existing rule, you could just add that dependency somewhere else in your Makefile...

> To be more specific, the solution needs to be written in a way that allows the makefile to be processed with other make implementations.

I don't think this would work in other make implementations... One possible solution is to create a `GNUmakefile` that would [`include`](https://www.gnu.org/software/make/manual/html_node/Include.html#Include) the actual `Makefile` and also add GNU make specific extensions.

You could also probably make GNU make ignore a rule such as `.WAIT` by defining it as a dummy rule in your `GNUmakefile`.

I hope these pointers are helpful!

Comment: GNUmakefile is not a solution in anobject oriented makefile system. I did already mention to use $(WAIT) that could  be empty or contain .WAIT. A feasible solution would be something that  could be controlled by make macro content or by including different rule files. I need to have a look at your proposal and check how many gmake specific rule files I would need. This finally decides whether it could be done this way.

Comment: I don't really know what you mean by object oriented makefile system... In any case, I don't think there's a way to have GNU make execute dependencies serially (when otherwise parallelizing.) In other words, I don't think something like `.NO_PARALLEL: install` exists in GNU make. Using order-only prerequisites (like explained above) should be able to get you to order directories before the files they contain, but the feature is unfortunately GNU make specific, so you need to find a way to trigger that in GNU make only and ignore it on other make implementations...

Comment: The schily makefilesystem includes object specific make rules that depend on the task, the platform, the compiler and the make utility. This is implemented via make macros that contain strings that depend on the current environment. The content of the make macros is controlled via pattern macro expansions that are common to all modern make implementations.

Comment: Based on your idea, I could create a useful solution. See my own answer to my question.

Answer (score 6):

You need to add dependencies so that directories are created before the files under them.

It is possible to use a "marker" file for the dependency on the directory, that way creating a file under it won't touch the timestamp of the directory. That doesn't require any GNU make specific features either.

In your example:

```
install: dir/file

dir/.marker:
        mkdir -p dir
        touch dir/.marker

dir/file: dir/.marker
        cp source dir/file
```

You can use something like `.directory` or `.dir` or `.folder` for the marker file...

Comment: `.directory` is used in KDE to store file manager metadata, so it would be safer to avoid this one. I personally think `.created` would be a nice choice.

Comment: I used this method in former times for directories that are created in the internal build tree, but it does not look nice if you e.g. create a marker file named `/usr/share/man/man1/.marker`

Comment: @schily You could create the markers elsewhere, such as in the source tree, name them after the encoded directory. (With the drawback that removing the directory won't delete the marker.) Another option is incorporating the `mkdir -p` commands in each of the file rules. I still think the order-only prerequisites in GNU make are a better approach, assuming you can find a way to incorporate the proprietary feature into your build and have a fallback for it...